# How to compare two rows in pandas (across all columns), and sum the output?

Tags: python, pandas, churn

I have data like this-

```
    User1  User2  User3  User4  User5  User6  User7  User8
w1      1      1      1      1      0      1      1      1
w2      0      1      0      0      1      1      1      1
w3      0      0      1      1      1      1      1      1
w4      1      1      1      0      0      0      0      1
w5      1      0      1      0      1      1      1      0
w6      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1
```

Now what I want to do is compare every two consecutive weeks, and find all cases where the change is 1->0 .

So output for the above data would be something like this-

```
    Column
w1      n/a    
w2      3   
w3      1
w4      4   
w5      2 
w6      0
```

Comment: I am not understanding, are you counting the position of the change or number of changes in this output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

could also do it like this:

```
(df > df.shift(-1)).sum(axis=1)
```

Comment: This works, but the final df was one row shifted up as compared to the one that I wanted. Used shift to get it the way I wanted, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Let say the dataframe name is df, so you can achieve it by

```
abs(df.diff()).sum(axis=1)
```